# HTK creating lab files

Tags: file, label, htk

have anyone some tutorial or does anyone know , how to creating separately .lab files for every .wav file? I found it, that some script creates one .mlf file with label for every sound, but it not that I want

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To annotate manually u can use HTKtools/HSLAb, or [SFS (windows)](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/)
To manipulate existing label files(*.lab), i.e. extract/join/anything? use HTKTools/HLed